# How to display an html element on top of a full screen element?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video-streaming, fullscreen

I'm working on a web based video chat portal and would like to display a small video stream of the user while the user is in fullscreen mode. Basically, I want to place a selfview div on top of a fullscreen element. Here is a simplied example of the html structure:

```
<div class="fullscreen-element">
        <div class="main-video-container">
            <video class="main-video"></video>
        </div>
    </div>

// In another area of the html

    <video class="self-view overlay-element"></video>

// Css example

   .self-view {
       position: absolute;
       z-index: 2147483647;
   }
```

Here are the problems I'm running into:
 - the selfview overlay div cannot be place within the fullscreen element.
 - maxing ou the z-index on the overlay doesn't work either.
 - displaying a new element apon entering fullscreen will not work because it inturrupts the socket.

Other information:
 - I'm using the `.requestFullscreen()` method to enter fullscreen mode.

I'm also open to alternative methods for entering fullscreen as long as they support overlaying.

Comment: _"maxing ou the z-index on the overlay doesn't work either"_ Are you sure that its position is either `absolute`, `fixed` or `relative`? Static elements don't respect a `z-index`. Also, what element do you call `.requestFullscreen()` on? If it's only the other person's video, it's understandable that the selfview won't be displayed

Comment: The selfview overlay is position: absolute. And .requestFullscreen() is being called on the 2nd parent container up from other persons video tag. Givving the appeareance of a fullscreen video while allowing control buttons to remain on the screen when in fullscreen.

Comment: Can you post as little code as you can but so we can reproduce the problem, or at least see what's wrong? I tried something here, but I don't know if it corresponds to your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/zrxewhgL/

Comment: Thank you for creating that example. The difference between my code and your example is; I can't put my small-video and large-video elements inside the same container.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know of a way to do it if it's not inside the fullscreen element... http://jsfiddle.net/j40s2bvd/ _(in that example, the video stops as you said)_

Comment: No worries, your examples were very helpful. I may be able to append the video element like you did, and reset the stream.